# error al insertar un valor boolean en los parametros de androd volley

Tags: android-studio, android-volley

tengo una clase que es para registrar un cliente, y en uno de los parametros es neceserio que envie un estado boleano(true) y almacenarlo en la base de datos mysql, pero cuando introduzco el valor True en uno de los parametreos me sale error.

```
public void realizarRegistro(){
    String url = "http://localhost/registrar.php";
    request = Volley.newRequestQueue(ActivityAcceso.this);

    StringRequest post = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> credenciales = new HashMap<>();
            credenciales.put("nombre", "nombre");
            credenciales.put("apellido", "apellido");
            credenciales.put("fecha_nacimiento", "fecha_nacimiento");
            credenciales.put("direccion_domicilio", "direccion domicilio");
            credenciales.put("numero_celular", "celular");
            credenciales.put("estado_civil", "estado_civil");
            credenciales.put("genero", "genero");
            credenciales.put("pais", "pais");
            credenciales.put("correo_electronico", "correo_electronico");
            credenciales.put("contrasena","contraseña");
            credenciales.put("foto_perfil","null");
            credenciales.put("estado", false); //aqui me salta el error
            return credenciales;
        }
    };
    request.add(post);
}
```

Como puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: Creo que seria mejor manejarlo con un estado de 1= true, 0 = false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mi me pasaba lo mismo pero al hacer un Put, lo solucione enviando el parámetro en 0, es decir:  credenciales.put("estado", "0");
Pero lo mas recomendable es que si el parametro siempre sera falso por lo que veo que envias, es mejor que desde la estructura de la base de datos lo pongas por default false, y luego cuando quieras actualizarlo a true ya solo haces un put en una consulta cuando quieras que sea true.

Comment: Si, eso fue lo que tuve que hacer, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es obvio, estas declarando el HashMap para que reciba como clave y valor, un String.

```
HashMap<String, String> ...
```

Si a este HashMap le pasas como valor un booleano claramente te dará error.

Para que puedas pasarle tanto valores String como booleanos, tienes que declarar el valor del HashMap como tipo Object.

```
HashMap<String, Object> ...
```

Comment: obiamente ya me habia dado cuenta de eso, y tambien lo intente hacerlo como dices declarando un HashMap<String, Object> pero igual da error porque el metodo getParams es un metodo protegido de volley y me obliga que si o si le retorne un hashMap de tipo <String, String>